# Rtsp for SJCAM 4000 Air

Tags: rtsp

There are rtsp links available for SJ4000 wifi, 5000 and so on. However, there seems to be no documentation found for SJ4000 Air. Has anyone had any experience with fetching the streams via rtsp for this model?